# author profile info in a content type

Tags: entities, nodes

Need to print the profile fields of author of a node in a particular  content type

I am using support tickets for my home owners association website. where in users can login in and create tickets for house keeping, electrical etc. Support tickets modules provides a content type support ticket which is been used for ticket creation. I would like to add profile fields to above content type  example:apartment no, contact nos of the user who creates the ticket node so that the support team looking at the ticket know the contact info.

I am presently on D7
Thanks

Comment: Use Views module and make a content view in relation with Content authored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Views module and make a content view in relation with Content authored.

[image]